# How can I query for a movie name from a specific genre in two tables that need to be joined?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

The goal is to list all the movies of a particular genre, such as 'Adenture'.

I have two tables:

```
(1) movies
  id
  name
  rank
  year
  PRIMARY

(2) movies_genre
  genre
  movie_id
```

I joined them using the following command:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN movies_genres on movies.id = movies_genres.movie_id;
```

the result is this(shortened):

```
| id     | name        | year | rank | movie_id | genre     |
+--------+-------------+------+------+----------+-----------+
| 930905 | TestMovie   | 2000 |    4 |   9309   | Music     |
| 991327 | Get Swift   | 2016 |   10 |   991327 | Adventure |
| 991326 | CommunityO  | 2016 |   10 |   991326 | Comedy    |
| 192017 | Lil Mermaid | 1989 |  7.3 |   192017 | Family    |
| 192017 | Lil Mermaid | 1989 |  7.3 |   192017 | Animation |
```

So how do I list the movies of say 'Adventure'

Note: I am new to sql and have been tasked with some difficult practice. I spent a lot of time on this and haven't gotten anywhere, this is my last resort.

Thank you.

Comment: add `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment you are looking for the `WHERE` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM movies 
LEFT JOIN movies_genres 
ON movies.id = movies_genres.movie_id
WHERE movies_genres.genre = "Adventure"
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS** : You have to add condition on `genre` and if you need to select only those records from both tables whose genre = `Adventure` then I would like to suggest `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` but it depends upon your requirement. Check the solution below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM movies m 
INNER JOIN movies_genres mg on m.id = mg.movie_id
    AND mg.genre = 'Adventure'
```

Avoid selecting unnecessary columns by defining the `column names` if you really don't wanna all the columns in the `SELECT` instead of `*` like `SELECT m.id, m.name, mg.genre....`

Comment: Can you explain the 'm' and 'mg'?

Comment: These are table's alias name and we can use these short names where needed instead of using long table names.